# Open the external pdf reader

Tags: objective-c, ipad

My app creates a pdf, that can be opened in the regular menü and then viewed, but not in the app. How to programatically open pdf in the ipad reader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to set the delegate in your header's ViewController:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>
```

Then you'll have to implement this method:

```
- (UIViewController *)documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    return self;
}
```

And then, when you catch which pdf has to be opened:

```
    NSString *sPathPDF = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"name.pdf"]]; //path example for a local stored pdf
    NSURL *urlPDF = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:sPathPDF];
    UIDocumentInteractionController *dicPDF = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: urlPDF];
    [dicPDF setDelegate:self];
    [dicPDF presentPreviewAnimated: YES];
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos. Thats exactly what i mean. And sorry for my bad english :-)